# How to develop Lombok in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I would like to fork Lombok so I can add to it what I need. I'm using Eclipse Neon.

I cloned the rep locally and managed to compile the jar by running the ant `build.xml`. However, when trying to change the code autocomplete doesn't work - I get the error "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project". The colored syntax is also amiss. The project isn't listed as a Java project `J` in eclipse. Pretty sure I didn't configure it right.

The short readme says to run `ant eclipse`, but I guess I don't know how to do that and if it'll solve everything. What are the detailed steps to achieve this?

Furthermore, when (if) I will be able to make the changes, will I need to build and install the jar each time in order for it to work in eclipse, or is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a working Eclipse setup:

- [Install ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)
- Make sure `ant` is on your path
- Open a command line
- Run `ant eclipse`. This creates the necessary `.project` and `.classpath` files for Eclipse.
- Open the project in Eclipse

To work on transformations, you want to run `ant setupJavaOracle8TestEnvironment`. This creates an Eclipse launch file, that's accessible from the Debug menu under the name `RunLombokTests OracleJDK8`.

In `<project root>/test/transform/resource`, if you add a file in the `before` directory that contains your annotation, it gets picked up by the test framework. this is the easiest way to see if your transformation works as expected. Since by that time you didn't yet create the accompanying "after" files, the test will fail, and the console window will show the the generated/transformed file. To speed up development, you can override the `accept(File file)` method in `lombok.transform.TestWithEcj` to only process your files.

Once your transformation delivers the expected results in the tests, run `ant dist`, and the new lombok jar is located in the `<project root>/dist` directory.

You do need to install it, but since you typically use the tests while working on the transformation, you only do it at the end.

Comment: Next question: I see the launch file in the root directory, but I'm not sure what debug menu you mean. I can right click and Run As (or Debug As) and then I get the error `Launch configuration RunLombokTests OracleJDK8 references non-existing project lombok.`

Comment: You can find it under the "green bug" button or in the main menu Run > Debug History. Possibly, the Eclipse project must be named "lombok" in order for it to work.

Comment: Yup, "Lombok" is not good. Has to be "lombok". Do you guys intend to update the Readme on github with information such as in this answer?

Comment: I used your tip to override `accept` in `TestWithEcj`, and I did it also for `TestWithDelombok` to make it even faster. It's still processing ~200 files. Can it be reduced even more?